# How to pass parameters from one function to the next in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a basic question about how to structure my code.

I'm creating a simple gui to search and return my company's financial data. This data exists in a series of excel files, and I use pandas to merge, filter, and return tables or values. My present code is quite inefficient, whereby I import relevant Excel files each time I call a search. I would rather import these Excel files upon launch and commit them to the program's memory while the program runs.

I believe that my attempt fails because I don't know how to pass arguments from one function to the next.  I'm sure that I'm using this "self" operator incorrectly. Looking for best practices here, and a Pythonic approach. Thank you in advance!

```
import pandas as pd

def getData(self):
    self.Excel1 = pd.read_excel(r'asdf')
    self.Excel2 = pd.read_excel(r'fdsa')

def func1(): 
    df1 = getData.Excel1
    df2 = getData.Excel2
    df3 = df1 + df2
    return df3

func1()
```

Comment: This should help. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: `self` represents an instance of a class, but you only have functions here. Do you know the principal first class functions ?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to pass a function as an argument, and geeks for geeks has a great article on 'decorators' that do exactly that. Link below:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/passing-function-as-an-argument-in-python/

However, could you perhaps just combine the two functions as one? i.e.:

```
 def getData():

    d1 = pd.read_excel(r'asdf')
    d2 = pd.read_excel(r'fdsa')
    d3 = d1 + d2

    return d3
```

I think the advantage of doing this is that you reduce the number of things that python needs to hold in memory. However the disadvantage is that you won't be able to access d1 or d2.

I hope this helps, I can't think of anything else based on the information in the question.

Comment: What you've described is actually my current solution, so I'm glad we're on the same page there. As for my needs, combining the Excel imports with the data manipulation causes the program to run slowly, since it needs to import the whole dataset before examining it. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: One solution that might help reduce the time it takes for your program to run is to save your data as a CSV instead of an excel. Excel is a file written in binary format, and has a lot of 'additional features' that you might not necessarily need such as text size, font, user interface, etc. 

A CSV on the other hand is a plain text file that just stores data values (no frills). I had a similar issue with a project that analysed lots of financial data and the use of CSV files significantly improved the speed with which pd was able to read it.

Comment: This is a good idea. I currently have them in Excel because these are standard-issue quarterly reports that many of my peers use and reference. Might be worth trying csv. Thanks for the feedback!